# Difference between matplotlib.image and cv2.imread

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib

When i read a grayscale image with matplotlib.image it shows dimension (512,512) and type (float32) but when i use cv2.imread for the same image it shows (512,512,3) and type uint8. Why is it so? Is cv2.imread command automatically converted image to BGR format, because of default flag. ( I am using python 3 and opencv2.) Following is code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.image as mpimage
img = cv2.imread('image_1.png')
img1=mpimage.imread('image_1.png')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, by default it reads BGR and if you want to read a grayscale image you need to use the second argument in imread. From the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html#read-an-image):

> #### Read an image
>
> Use the function cv2.imread() to read an image. The
> image should be in the working directory or a full path of image
> should be given.
>
> Second argument is a flag which specifies the way image should be
> read.
>
> 1. cv2.IMREAD_COLOR : Loads a color image. Any transparency of image will
>    be neglected. It is the default flag.
> 2. cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE : Loads
>    image in grayscale mode
> 3. cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED : Loads image as such
>    including alpha channel Note Instead of these three flags, you can
>    simply pass integers 1, 0 or -1 respectively.
>
> See the code below:
>
> ```
> import numpy as np import cv2
>
> #Load an color image in grayscale 
> img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
> ```

So, if you want to read in a grayscale image by default you need to have the second argument in imread as a 1, not 0. This subtle change to your code below should read in the same image format in both instances

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.image as mpimage
img = cv2.imread('image_1.png', 1)
img1=mpimage.imread('image_1.png')
```

Comment: is that mean if i want to change gray image to bgr than no need to write separate code for this, i can use just `img = cv2.imread('image_1.png')` for this

Comment: Yes, if you read in a grayscale image as BGR then you will have three channels representing the B,G & R values for the gray image